# How to select certain rows from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

1- How can I select 5 different values inside a column ?

Example:

```
**Car**

Fiat
Fiat
Hyundai
Mitsubish
Kia
Kia
Hyundai
renault
porsche
```

How can I select the rows that has (Fiat, hyundai , Kia) for example ?

I tried this:

```
df.loc[df['cars'].isin("Fiat", "hyundai" , "Kia")]
```

But no success

Second problem:

In R we have pipe operator in order to reduce the number of new Copies*. What is the best solution in python ?

*Update - Is it a good way to create manipulation data of multiple steps ?

In this example:

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
df1 = df1[(df1['Meses'] != 'Total') & (df1['Orcado x Realizado'] == 'Realizado') & (df1['Area Negocio'] == 'Total das Áreas de Negócios')]
df1['Meses'] = df1['Meses'].replace({'M1': '01', 'M2': '02', 'M3': '03', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M6': '06', 'M7': '07', 'M8': '08', 'M9': '09', 'M10': '10', 'M11': '11', 'M12': '12'})
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Ano.astype(str) + '-' + df1.Meses.astype(str))
df1['Values'] = (df1['Values'] / 1000000)
df1 = df1[['Date', 'Contas Resultado', 'Values']]
```

Is there a way to make this code shorter, without having to create new variables ?

Comment: Could you include what the original dataframe looked like?

Comment: For your first problem, just put your car brands inside a list within your `.isin()`: `df.loc[df['cars'].isin(["Fiat", "hyundai" , "Kia"])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

With this code:

```
df.loc[df['cars'].isin("Fiat", "hyundai" , "Kia")]
```

You need to use a list:

```
df.loc[df['cars'].isin(["Fiat", "hyundai" , "Kia"])]
```

For the second question:

I'm not sure what you mean by creating new variables. It looks like you only have one (`df1`)

## Edit

This code:

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
df1 = df1[(df1['Meses'] != 'Total') & (df1['Orcado x Realizado'] == 'Realizado') & (df1['Area Negocio'] == 'Total das Áreas de Negócios')]
df1['Meses'] = df1['Meses'].replace({'M1': '01', 'M2': '02', 'M3': '03', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M6': '06', 'M7': '07', 'M8': '08', 'M9': '09', 'M10': '10', 'M11': '11', 'M12': '12'})
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Ano.astype(str) + '-' + df1.Meses.astype(str))
df1['Values'] = (df1['Values'] / 1000000)
df1 = df1[['Date', 'Contas Resultado', 'Values']]
```

Can be reduced to:

```
df1.dropna(inplace = True) # shortened
df1 = df1[(df1['Meses'] != 'Total') & (df1['Orcado x Realizado'] == 'Realizado') & (df1['Area Negocio'] == 'Total das Áreas de Negócios')]
df1['Meses'].replace({'M1': '01', 'M2': '02', 'M3': '03', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M4': '04', 'M5': '05', 'M6': '06', 'M7': '07', 'M8': '08', 'M9': '09', 'M10': '10', 'M11': '11', 'M12': '12'}, inplace = True) # shortened
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Ano.astype(str) + '-' + df1.Meses.astype(str))
df1['Values'] = (df1['Values'] / 1000000)
df1 = df1[['Date', 'Contas Resultado', 'Values']]
```

Can't really do much more "shortening" besides using the `inplace=` parameters when available.

Comment: When I write "df1= ... " many times,  is it a good way to do multiple manipulation steps ? Or it makes more proccess than necessary ?

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm: every new copy of df1 variable is necessary in this case ?

Comment: @Cesar that is correct. You might be able to use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html, but I can't confirm without seeing some of your data.